# This question about how to convince management to use individual offices is not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/how-do-i-convince-my-boss-to-get-rid-of-our-open-office-and-give-us-individual-o

This question is not a duplicate, as it is about convincing management, not the productivity value of individual offices.

Comment: How do you make someone else do something they do not want to do is off topic.  The only way to change the question to be on topic is to ask about the benefits of the 2 plans... which is the question its closed as a duplicate of

Answer (score 2):

The first step in convincing management that open offices are a bad a idea is to gather the evidence. Which is exactly what the other question does.

I feel the best answer to the question is "see other question"

Comment: good point about first step. "How do I convince mgmt" sounds much of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/165773 "'asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem'"). Convincing is a _solution_ but the real _problem_ is gaining evidence of productivity loss/gain. With this _XY-gap_ properly filled in, duplication becomes rather obvious

Comment: In which case what you've said here could be stated as an answer to the question. "The first step is to gather information...- Next...".